# Calculating the base charge in project 1 draft rental car in python

Tags: python

I am trying to output 300.00 for the base charge for my rental car project in python but using codio. 300.0 is the result i receive for the below code, what am i missing??

```
baseCharge = 0
if rentalCode == "B":[enter image description here][1]
    baseCharge = (rentalPeriod) * (budgetCharge)
elif rentalCode == "D":
    baseCharge = float(rentalPeriod) * float(dailyCharge)
elif rentalCode == "W":
    baseCharge = float(rentalPeriod) * float(weeklyCharge)    
print(baseCharge)
```

LAST RUN on 1/28/2019, 9:37:55 AM
Check 1 failed
Output:
(B)udget, (D)aily, or (W)eekly rental?
Number of Days Rented:
D
5
300.0
Expected:
(B)udget, (D)aily, or (W)eekly rental?
Number of Days Rented:
D
5
300.00

Comment: Try `print("{0:.2f}".format(baseCharge))`. (I suppose no need of `float(...` then)

Comment: you are amazing. I added what you suggested and removed the float(... from most of them but then i ran into a syntax error on one of the lines, therefore i added float(...back to the line below and the check passed!              baseCharge = 0
if rentalCode == "B":
    baseCharge = rentalPeriod * budgetCharge
elif rentalCode == "D":
    baseCharge = float(rentalPeriod) * float(dailyCharge)
elif rentalCode == "W":
    baseCharge = rentalPeriod * weeklyCharge  
print("{0:.2f}".format(baseCharge))

Answer (score 2):

You need to enter:

`print("{0:.2f}".format(baseCharge))`

in order for Python to output the float in two digits.

Basically add `("{0:.2f}".format)` in front of the baseCharge `print` command.